# What's wrong with code.ros.org?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,everyone.I am a new university student who want to study ros.I had installed the ros system successfully and made the robot running.Now I want to get other package to study,but I found that 'code.ros.org' cannot be visited.It has some svn package which I want.I can visit the youtube by vpn but I cannot visit 'code.ros.org'.
What's wrong with it?And,how can I get those package in another way?Please,thank you so much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264070/what%27s-wrong-with-code.ros.org?/) by [rong888](https://answers.ros.org/users/30799/rong888/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What packages do you need to get the source code of? Usually their at http://wiki.ros.org/%PKG_NAME% (replace `%PKG_NAME%` with the actual name) contains links to their development repository. If there aren't then maybe google search the package name.

[code.ros.org has been terminated years ago](http://answers.ros.org/question/215392/coderosorgsvn-down/).

---

UPDATE: If you had web searched, it should have been easy to find a github repo for `3d_navigation`... I've [updated the wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/3d_navigation?action=diff&rev2=25&rev1=24) with the latest repo location.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rong888](https://answers.ros.org/users/30799/rong888/) on 2017-06-18**:
Thanks for your answer.The url is http://wiki.ros.org/3d_navigation. I want this package but I cannot.Does it exist in otherwhere?

**Comment by [rong888](https://answers.ros.org/users/30799/rong888/) on 2017-06-21**:
Thank you very much.I can get it.